# how to reverse quick explode

Tags: particles, effects

How can I reverse the quick explode effect? meaning, after the object turns into particles how can I create an animation to reconstruct this particle system to its original object?

Comment: If you bake the particle animation to keyframes then you can can just go to the dopesheet and select all the keyframes and then push *Ctrl+M> Mirror By Times over Current Frame, with the current frame in the middle. Or just press *S> X > -1* like when modeling.

Comment: How do you "bake the particle animation to keyframes" @jakemoyo?